# How to integrate a special font (.ttf) in an Android application?

Tags: java, android, textview, customization

I want to add a file .ttf to be able to customize the font of my textView in my application.

I wonder how the exploited?

I download the file on [DaFont](http://www.dafont.com/fr/).

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: https://www.google.it/search?q=android+custom+font&aq=f&oq=android+custom+font&aqs=chrome.0.57j65j60j59j60j62.6562j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

First result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, copy the font to your `/assets` folder in your project, then to set the `Typeface` of your `TextView`, you can do the following:

```
Typeface myFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "dafont.ttf");
myTextView.setTypeface(myFont);
```

Edit: corrected directory